# Displaying php in WebView (Android Studio)

Tags: php, android, android-studio, android-webview

So I have this code for displaying `www.google.com` in a WebView widget in Android Studio and it works fine:

```
   mWebview  = new WebView(this);
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    final Activity activity = this;

    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mWebview .loadUrl("www.google.com");
    setContentView(mWebview );
```

I actually got that from one of the questions here in Stack. So what I want to do is display my php file instead. I tried replacing `mWebview .loadUrl("www.google.com");` with `mWebview .loadUrl("localhost/index.php");` but it doesn't work. How do I achieve this?

Comment: localhost on device is obviously device itself, please search similar questions here on SO

Comment: are you running a webserver with php on your phone? `localhost` is basically "talk to myself", and "myself" is your phone, since that's where the code is running.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and its work for me..

```
         wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        wv1.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2/your_page.php");
            wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how this works. @user6880336 kind of correct but instead of 10.0.2.2 as the IP address it needs to be the server IP.

```
    mWebview .loadUrl("192.168.1.105/Lab4/Task1/index.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

First things firsts, check your ip address if you are connected to a network. Run cmd and type "ipconfig" get the ipv4 address. Now you got your ip address change the localhost to your ipaddress. Well obviously if you use localhost or 10.0.2.2, your app might not run properly. Remember you do not have database or any webserver on your device alone.